# Infinite-loop in Redux and one more error

Tags: reactjs, redux, infinite-loop

I have a table (10X10) which renders random values. If I push the arrow (up and down) in header, the column must be changed to increasing or reducing column. After that all rows must be changed.

My code:

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const dataCompleted = generateNewData(10, dataColumnNames.columnNames.length,
      dataColumnNames.columnNames);

    this.store = Redux.createStore(
      appReducers,
      {
        table: {
          header: dataColumnNames.columnNames,
          data: dataCompleted,
          footer: generateNewFooter(dataCompleted)
        },
        sorting: {
          sortType: null,
          columnId: null,
          test: null
        },
        showDetails: {
          rowId: null
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
   return <Provider store={this.store}>
    <div className="container">
      <Table />
    </div>
   </Provider>
   }
}
export default App;
```

**Table.jsx**

```
class TableBlock extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if (this.props.sorting.sortType === 1) {
      let newData1 = (oldData) => {
        let newData = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < oldData.length; i++) {
          newData[i] = oldData[i].sort(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
          });
        }
        return newData;
      }
      this.props.dispatchNewData(newData1(this.props.data));
    } else {
      let newData1 = (oldData) => {
        let newData = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < oldData.length; i++) {
          newData[i] = oldData[i].sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
          });
        }
        return newData;
      }
      this.props.dispatchNewData(newData1(this.props.data));
    }
  }

  renderBody() {
    let result = this.props.table.data.map(function (dataItem, index) {
      return <Body content={dataItem} key={index} />
    });

    return result;
  }

  render() {
    return <table className="table">
      <Header />
      <tbody>{this.renderBody()}</tbody>
      <Footer />
    </table>
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = function(state = {}) {
  return {
    table: state.table,
    data: state.table.data,
    sorting: state.sorting,
    columnId: state.sorting.columnId,
    showDetails: state.showDetails
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatchNewData: function(data) {
      dispatch(table(data));
    }
  }
}

const Table = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableBlock);
export default Table;
```

**Reducer - table.js**

```
import { TABLE } from '../constants/table';

export function table(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TABLE:
      return {
        state: state,
        data: action.data
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**Action - table.js**

```
import { TABLE } from '../constants/table’;

export function table(data) {
  return {
    type: TABLE,
    data
  }
}
```

**My errors:**

1. props.table.data - isn’t changing
2. if I push 3 or more time the button - appearing infinity loop
3. after the first pushing - appearing error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.content.map')

I think object props is changing. It is not good.

Comment: Can you post your reducer for props.tabel as well? This code is confusing to me: ```    dispatchNewData: function(data) {
      dispatch(table(data));
    }``` but I'm not sure how it works without seeing more of the reducer.

Comment: @AnilRedshift completed.